# ¿Cómo ver los commits locales no subidos al repositorio remoto?

Tags: git

Hice varios **commits en local** que tengo pendientes de enviar al remoto (PUSH), ¿cómo puedo visualizar estos commits pendientes de enviar?

Answer (score 6):

Suponiendo que estás en la rama "master", puedes utilizar:

```
git log origin/master..HEAD
```

De esta manera, comparas el contenido de la rama "master" en remoto (en el servidor) con HEAD, que es el punto en el que lo has dejado tú con tus commits.

También puedes utilizar:

```
git log @{u}..
```

Donde `@{u}` se refiere a la parte "alta" de tu rama actual.

([fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8182309))

Comment: tambien con git diff  `git diff origin/master..HEAD` y es valido la linea `git log --branches --not --remotes`